# video loads, but clicking play does nothing?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, video

so going off my last question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332220/video-loads-fine-sometimes-and-other-times-it-takes-forever-to-load-or-doesnt/44332330#44332330)

I found a very strange glitch that I do not know how to fix. I tested in google chrome, and firefox both of which had this glitch happen.

so this glitch only happens on my pages that are dedicated to the video that just displays more information about the video. The videos load fine on my video carousel on my main page though.

The glitch only happens when my video loads. what happens is my video which I have set to preload, and autoplay will just get stuck at 0:00 even if I click the play button it will not play?? to fix it I click somewhere into the video, and it will then start playing fine???

I have no idea why this happens, but if someone knows what is causing this please let me know!! another thing is this glitch happens almost 90% of the time when I go to the dedicated page, and the other 10% of the time the video will autoplay fine. yet the video works fine about 95% of the time on my main page where it is being played in my video carousel.

I am using a video tag to display the video.

```
<video id="videoLoad1" preload="auto" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Video/")@item.clip" autoplay="" loop="" muted style="width:100%;"></video>
```

could this just be an issue with my computer?? I tried clearing the %temp% files and clearing all my cache I also used ccleaner but the issue still happens.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no clue what is happening, but I ended up just using a backup of my website which I saved yesterday which works when debugging, but when I publish them to IIS I still get the glitch of where the videos don't load, but when I am debugging on visual studios the videos load fine! at least it works in visual studios now, before it wasn't working in visual studios or IIS so IIS is still probably just loading the old files for some reason, but I will fix that later.